# Find k Percentiles of a Data Set

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

The task is to `find` the `k` `percentiles` in a given `unsorted` Data Set. A Data set has in reality k - 1 percentiles. What is a percentile?

> Percentiles are the `k-1` elements in a `sorted` Data Set where they `divide` the Data set in `k` `equal` sub-sets in size (with +1 or -1).

For example, in the given array: [2 5 `7` 10 17 `21` 34 48]
the bold numbers are the percentiles for k = 3.

Now the code I have provided you below, is false. It doesn't compute all the values of k. The core idea is that we take the unsorted array and firstly we compute (with `select`) the `m = floor(k/2)` index of the Data set which will be near the middle of our data set. Then with `partition` we have a *"somewhat"* sorted dataset with the left values of the `m` being all smaller percentiles, and the right values being all larger percentiles.Then with recursion we do it again for the next (k/2)/2 element.

I can't think of a way that we can compute the other percentiles, and end up with a complexity of `Θ(n) = nlog(k)`

```
find_percentiles(A,p,q,k):
  select(A, floor(k/2)
  partition(A,p,q,floor(k/2)) #partition around floor(k/2)

  if (floor(k/2)) ==1: 
    return

  find_percentiles(A,p,floor(k/2), floor(k/2))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following `c#` code might be a starting point for your own experiments:

```csharp
    private static int[] find_percentiles(int[] A, int k)
    {
        int len = A.Length;

        if ((len < 1) || (k < 1))
        {
            //  no percentiles left: return empty array
            return [];
        }

        if (len <= k)
        {
            //  array too short: cannot devise percentiles
            return A;
        }

        //  it is more efficient to use a fast median selection
        //  https://rcoh.me/posts/linear-time-median-finding/
        //  or https://www.techieclues.com/blogs/how-to-calculate-the-median-of-an-array-in-csharp
        int pivot = A.OrderBy(x => x).ElementAt(len / 2); 

        if (k < 2)
        {
            return [pivot];
        }

        int[] upper = A.Where(x => x > pivot).ToArray();
        int[] lower = A.Where(x => x < pivot).ToArray();
        double gap = (len - (k - 1.0)) / ((double)k);
        int kUpper = (int)(upper.Length / (gap + 1));
        int kLower = k - 1 - kUpper;
        int[] upperK = find_percentiles(upper, kUpper);
        int[] lowerK = find_percentiles(lower, kLower);
        return lowerK.Union([pivot]).Union(upperK).ToArray();
    }
```